# GTK Python. How to add a key event in a scrolled window?

Tags: python, gtk

I'm working with GTK on Python. I have a scrolled window displayed on a window. I'm trying to add a key event that trigger an event when i press ENTER.
So far I tried this in different configurations but the key-press-event is never detected :

```
def press_space(self,event):
        if event.keyval == gtk.keysyms.space:
            self.validation=True
```

```
def selection_window(self):
    win= gtk.Window()
    win.set_name("Choose a point")
    win.set_size_request(400, 300)
    win.connect("destroy", self.graceful_exit)

    vbox = gtk.VBox(spacing=3)
    win.add(vbox)

    sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    sw.set_shadow_type(gtk.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN)
    sw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)

    store = gtk.ListStore(str, str, object)

    # Create the list
    for site in self.controller.KnownSites:
        if len(site) > 3:
            coll = site[3]
        else:
            coll = ''
        store.append([site[0], coll, site])
    treeview = gtk.TreeView(store)

    renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
    column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Location", renderer, text=0)
    treeview.append_column(column)
    renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
    column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Collection", renderer, text=1)
    treeview.append_column(column)

    sw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
    sw.add(treeview)

    
    vbox.connect("key-press-event", self.press_space)
    vbox.pack_start(sw,expand=True)

    win.show_all()

    if self.validation==True:
        win.destroy()

    gtk.main()
```

I also try with to connect a gtk.entry to the box. It manage to detect the key-press-event but I don't manage to mix it with the scrolled window.

I have any advices...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
self.treeview.connect("row-activated", self.test)
self.treeview.set_activate_on_single_click(False)

def test(self, tree_view, path, column):
    print('Return!')
```